# Is there a method for versioning header and library dependencies in C?

Tags: c, gcc

We have a repo that contains library functions for example (gcc is used to compile and link).

```
//print.h
#ifndef __PRINT_H_
#define __PRINT_H_

#define MAX_ARRAY 10

void print_hex(int cal[]);

#endif

// print.c
#include <stdio.h>

void print_hex(int val[]) {

    for (int I=0;I<MAX_ARRAY;I++)   {
        printf("%i\n",val[I]);
    }

}
```

The above is compiled into a **libprint.a.1.0.0**. My app is then compiled using this library

```
//main.c
#include "print.h"

int main(int argc, int arg[]) {
    int vals[MAX_ARRAY];

    memset(vals,8,MAX_ARRAY*sizeof(int));
    print_hex(vals);
    return 0;
}
```

And everything is fine and works (assuming have typed the above out correctly). But then someone decides to make a change in the library where someone Makes the following change.

```
//print.h
...

#define MAX_ARRAY 50
...
```

The library is recompiled to **libprint.a.1.1.0**

This new static library is now used when compiling and linking our main.c. However, the new print.h was not copied to the include directory so the main.c is using an old print.h where **MAX_ARRAY** is smaller.

Now in this case we might get any behaviour as the print function runs off the end of the passed in array. As a user of the library there is no way to necessarily know that the header file is wrong until I compile and run the application, or perhaps even hours of running when the program starts to go crazy.

What is the standard way to avoid this issue?

Is there a way to add a version to a header file to ensure the correct library is linked?

I realise I could do this by creating a new function in print.c called get_version(), and use that in main.c to check against some defines in print.h to ensure veracity but I was wondering if there was a way without the user application having to specifically check library and header versions at run time.

Comment: Have you considered the use of `static_assert`s with the macros defining the version number?

Comment: Do not put code into headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. And don't do it.

The [libfuse](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse) library uses a macro `FUSE_USE_VERSION` that should be defined by the client to differentiate between different versions. Internally it works similar to [feature_test_macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html).

So in your library it would look like:

`print.h`:

```
#ifndef __PRINT_H_
#define __PRINT_H_

#if PRINT_USE_VERSION == 1

#define MAX_ARRAY 10
void print_hex_version_1(int cal[]);

static inline
void print_hex(int cal[]) {
   print_hex_version_1(val);
}

#elif PRINT_USE_VERSION == 2

#define MAX_ARRAY 50
void print_hex_version_2(int cal[]);
static inline
void print_hex(int cal[]) {
   print_hex_version_2(val);
}

#else
#error unknown PRINT_USE_VERSION
#endif

#endif
```

`print_version_1.c`:

```
#define PRINT_USE_VERSION  1
#include <stdio.h>

void print_hex_version_1(int val[]) {
    for (int I=0;I<MAX_ARRAY;I++)   {
        printf(“%i\n”,val[I]);
    }
}
```

`print_version_2.c`:

```
#define PRINT_USE_VERSION  2
#include <stdio.h>

void print_hex_version_2(int val[]) {
    for (int I=0;I<MAX_ARRAY;I++)   {
        printf(“%i\n”,val[I]);
    }
}
```

Or similar, hope you'll you get the idea. Using this method you can distribute all possible versions of your library at once. And clients can link against multiple versions of your library. Which ends up being spaghetti code, unstable, unreliable, unfixable and unmaintainable.

On a global scale, it makes no sense. Just create a api that isn't dependent on a macro definition and take the array size as an argument. Check if the size of the array is equal to some predefined value and notify your client with error code that he did something wrong.